# Titanium Appcelerator Android - keyboard not staying open

Tags: android, keyboard, titanium

I'm working on a Titanium Android app.  I have a series of text fields, and when I focus on the first one, the soft keyboard opens and then immediately closes. If I then tap on the second one, the keyboard opens and stays open, and I can go back to the first one and it stays open and everything is fine.
Text fields are created like this:

```
obj.softKeyboardOnFocus = Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS;
        obj.height = 40;
        obj.width = 200;
        obj.left = 4;
        obj.top = 3;
        obj.autocorrect = false;
        obj.autocapitalization = Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE;
        obj.focusable = true;
        //obj.clearButtonMode = Titanium.UI.INPUT_BUTTONMODE_ONFOCUS;
        obj.keyboardType = Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_URL;
        if (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth > 320) {
            obj.font = {
                fontSize : getAndroidNumbers(16, 22)
            };
            obj.top = getAndroidNumbers(3, 4);
            obj.height = getAndroidNumbers(40, 60);
            obj.width = getAndroidNumbers(200, 200);
        }


    var tf = Titanium.UI.createTextField(obj);
```

I also added listeners to all but the last edit field to fix a problem where the keyboard wasn't opening at all:

```
prevTf.addEventListener('return',function(){
            Ti.API.debug("return event listener firing for " + tag);
             tf.focus();
         });
```

prevTf is the previous text field in the list and tf is the current one, so when return ("Next") is clicked on one field, the next one is focused (and the keyboard stays open). Previously when Next was clicked focus would change to the next field, but the keyboard would close. Now Next is working, but the first field won't keep the keyboard open. Any ideas?

Comment: try removing `obj.softKeyboardOnFocus = Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS;`

Comment: Well that does seem to help.  The keyboard now stays open.  However, now if I press the Next button on the keyboard, focus goes to the next field and the keyboard closes.  I tried removing the event listener, but then I'm back to the keyboard not opening at all when the field is focused.

Comment: are you using titanium-alloy? or are you creating text fields inside controller code?

Comment: Not Alloy, just creating text fields in javascript.

Comment: I'm testing your code on Huawei P6 with Android 4.2.2. It works as expected - when the textfield gets focus / next button on keyboard is pressed, the keyboard is visible

Comment: I've seen or had this problem reported on Samsung and ZTC devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally clear with your question, what I understand is that:

1. You are facing issues with the keyboard auto-focus on window.
2. You need next button in your keyboard which will allow user to move to next text-field.

I will add the fix for above two points here, please comment if I miss something from your question.

**1. To remove auto-focus of keyboard :** We have 2 proper working solution for this.

Example 1 : Add/remove SOFT_KEYBOARD property of the first text-field.

```
var textField1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
   color: '#336699',
   top: 10, left: 10,
   width: 250, height: 60
});

//keyboard auto-focus code added here
textField1.softKeyboardOnFocus = Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_HIDE_ON_FOCUS;
textField1.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
   textField1.setSoftKeyboardOnFocus(Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_KEYBOARD_SHOW_ON_FOCUS);
   textField1.focus();
});
```

Example 2 : Add SOFT_KEYBOARD property to the current window. ( *This is much better but cursor is visible in the text-field* )

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   windowSoftInputMode: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN //keyboard auto-focus code added here
});

var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
   color: '#336699',
   top: 10, left: 10,
   width: 250, height: 60
});

win.add(textField);
win.open();
```

**2. To allow next button in keyboard :** Most of the android devices automatically handles the next button functionality but if you still want to specify these value you can use [returnKeyType](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-returnKeyType) property of text-field.

**Full example with two text-fields in a window, below :**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   backgroundColor: 'white',
   windowSoftInputMode: Titanium.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN //keyboard auto-focus code
});

var textField1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
   color: '#336699',
   top: 10, left: 10,
   width: 250, height: 60 , 
   returnKeyType: Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_NEXT //returnKeyType code here
});

var textField2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
   color: '#336699',
   top: 10, left: 10,
   width: 250, height: 60,
   returnKeyType: Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE //returnKeyType code here
});

win.add(textField1);
win.add(textField2);
win.open();
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: That isn't what I'm after - the problem is the keyboard is not displaying when it's supposed to.  I'm trying to show the keyboard, not hide it.  If you can provide a suggestion that will always show the keyboard when a text field has focus, that would be perfect.  As for the next button, it's there, but depending on exactly what code I'm running (I've tried several things to get this to work) it causes the keyboard to close.